# Fork() and global variable

Tags: c, fork

i know that when two variable have same address they gonna have the same value but in my case the var " a " have same address in child and parent process after fork .. but when i set a = 1 in child process the value of a in father process stay 5 ... why ? and thanks

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a = 5;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {
    printf("%s\n", " erreur while creating fils !");

  } else if (pid == 0){
      a = 1;
      printf("%s %d\n", "child", a);
      printf("%s %p\n", "child", &a);
      return printf("child done\n");
  } else {
    wait(0);
    printf("%s %d\n", "father", a);
    printf("%s %p\n", "father", &a);
    return printf("father done\n");
  }

}
```

Comment: Memory addresses are virtualised. Just because they return the same virtual address, they do not point to the same piece of physical memory.

Comment: After `fork()`, parent and child are different processes that run in different memory blocks. All the data of the parent process is duplicated into the child process.

Comment: Adding to @axiac answer, Linux will do lazy duplication to save memory which mean the duplication will occur once one of the process tries to modify the data

Comment: The `fork` call copies the process/address space: after that the two processes are two different, isolated entities. So if you change `a` in the parent before fork,   you see the copy of `a` in the child, but if you change `a` in the child (therefore after the `fork`) this is an object in a different address space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent and child processes have different address spaces after `fork()`.

[image]

Even if you use global variable, it's copied. When you try to change it, its copy value is changed.

> they still have the same memory address.. why ?

There is a disconnection between physical memory and the virtual address space of a process. It seems same memory addresses there, that's only the virtual address. For more, [4G address space and mapping](http://www.programering.com/a/MDO1kjNwATI.html)

Comment: And note that (virtual) addresses *have to* remain the same in the child, else every pointer value in it would be unusable.

Answer (score 2):

When you fork, the child becomes a ***copy*** of the parent process. The copy of the variable in the child process is totally disconnected from the variable in the parent process.

Comment: but they still have the same memory address.. why ?

Comment: @ÀbdøûGh That's part of the *copying*.

Answer (score 0):

When you use fork, you create a different processus which do not share memory with the first one.

(You can see threads for that)

Comment: yes i know that but why they have the same address and different value ??

Comment: they have the same address because they use virtual address
For your os they are not the sames addresses