# Why is the global variable shared after fork()?

Tags: c, signals, fork

To my understanding, after fork() occurs, the parent and child processes share the variable *until* some modification occurs in one of the processes. Once the parent or child modifies it, a duplicate is made and assigned - thus, they do not "share" the variable anymore.
(i.e. [Fork() and global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117670/fork-and-global-variable?rq=1))
So, I thought the following piece of code would print out "050":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int counter = 0;

void handler1(int sig) {
    printf("%d", counter);
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);
}
void handler2(int sig) {
    counter = 5;
    printf("%d", counter);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid;
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
    signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);
    if ((pid = fork())) {
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    } 
    else {
        wait(0);
        counter++;
        printf("%d", counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But instead, it prints "056".
It seems like:

Child prints 0.
Child modifies the value of 'counter' to 5.
Child prints 5.
Somehow, the modification affects the 'counter' of parent ... and parent prints 6.

How is this possible? Is it because the modification was made inside the signal handler? If so, do changes caused by signal handlers affect all processes accessing that global variable?

Comment: The child process may not have even started at the moment the modification happens since fork isn’t immediate. Therefore it may be that it shares the value after modification to 5. Maybe add a delay of one second to parent and two seconds to child to see if that affects things?

Answer (score 2):

> Somehow, the modification affects the 'counter' of parent ... and parent prints 6.

This is where you're confused. The parent process doesn't print anything; only the child process is printing, and only its `counter` variable is being modified.

The actual flow:

One process calls `fork()`. Now there's two processes, the parent and child.

The parent sends a `SIGUSR1` to the child with `kill()`, and exits. Remember that `fork()` in the parent returns the pid of the child, and 0 in the child. (Or it fails and returns an error that you should be checking for.)

The child's `SIGUSR1` handler function prints the value of `counter` (Currently 0), and then causes the `SIGUSR2` handler to be called. That one sets `counter` to 5, and prints it.

Finally, the body of the child in `main()` runs. `wait()` is called and returns an error because the child has no children of its own (This may happen before or after the signal handlers are run). Then it increments `counter` to 6, prints it, and exits.

The order of the signal handler and the `printf()` in main isn't fixed because you do nothing to synchronize things; running the program multiple times might give different results. And using `printf()` and other stdio functions in a signal handler isn't safe and may cause really bizarre behavior. See the Linux [signal-safety man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for details, and a list of what is safe to call from a signal handler.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused. I should've remembered that fork() returns 0 to the child process, not the parent.

Comment: I was aware that printf() isn't safe - actually this code is from the CSAPP website. The code is from one of its past exams. Still, I thank you for your detailed attention to point that out!

Comment: I don't know what CSAPP is, but if this is representative of the quality of code on that site, it's not one that should be used as a learning resource.